# Update current row with previous row sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table with some columns and I want to update current row data with previous adding current row another column value to it. Below is my table

```
   Date     Type      Temp   Value
2018-04-24  TypeA       0     5
2018-04-25  TypeA       0     12
2018-04-26  TypeA       0     21
2018-04-27  TypeA       0     14
2018-04-30  TypeA       0     16
2018-05-01  TypeA       0.6   18
2018-04-25  TypeB       0     20
2018-04-26  TypeB       0     81
2018-04-27  TypeB       1     42
2018-04-30  TypeB       0     65
2018-05-01  TypeB       0.6   22
```

I want output to be such that - value column = previous row value column + current row temp.

```
   Date     Type      Temp   Value
2018-04-24  TypeA       0     5
2018-04-25  TypeA       0     5
2018-04-26  TypeA       0     5
2018-04-27  TypeA       0     5
2018-04-30  TypeA       0     5
2018-05-01  TypeA       0.6   5.6
2018-04-25  TypeB       0     20
2018-04-26  TypeB       0     20
2018-04-27  TypeB       1     21
2018-04-30  TypeB       0     21
2018-05-01  TypeB       0.6   21.6
```

I have tried to write a query but I am only able to update previous row into current row.

The query I have used is:

```
UPDATE testTable
SET Value = (select ISNULL(lag(m2.Value,1) over(partition by Type order by Date),testTable.Value) as lag1
                    from testTable m2
                    where m2.Date= testTable.Date
                    and
                    m2.Type= testTable.Type
                   )
```

Comment: I suppose this is Microsoft SQL Server, starting from version 2012, you have LAG to do just that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Show us the query you are currently using so we can make suggestions to modify it.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues I implemented lag but It is updating previous row value into current. So basically on third row I am getting 12 instead of 5

Comment: @JeremyJ.I have added the query. I have used rownumber, cte also but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Can you identify the primary keys of the table please. This helps with update statements.

Comment: Looks like you want a [running total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server)

Comment: Where did the "81" and "42" go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach using a `First_Value()` and `Sum() over()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Date] date,[Type] varchar(50),[Temp] decimal(10,2),[Value] decimal(10,2))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('2018-04-24','TypeA',0,5)
,('2018-04-25','TypeA',0,12)
,('2018-04-26','TypeA',0,21)
,('2018-04-27','TypeA',0,14)
,('2018-04-30','TypeA',0,16)
,('2018-05-01','TypeA',0.6,18)
,('2018-04-25','TypeB',0,20)
,('2018-04-26','TypeB',0,81)
,('2018-04-27','TypeB',1,42)
,('2018-04-30','TypeB',0,65)
,('2018-05-01','TypeB',0.6,22)

;with cte0 as (
      Select  *
             ,NewValue = FIRST_VALUE(Value) over (Partition By [Type] Order By [Date]) 
                        +Sum(Temp) over (Partition By [Type] Order By [Date]) 
        From  @YourTable
)
Update cte0 set Value = NewValue
```

**The Updated Table**

[image]

Comment: perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: @DeepSharma Happy to help